# How do I set the SerDe XML schema correctly?

Tags: hive, hive-serde

I've got this XML:

```
  <AssetCrossReferences Ordered="false">
    <AssetCrossReference AssetID="F7961393-01" Type="Primary Image"/>
    <AssetCrossReference AssetID="M0504-01" Type="Vendor Logo"/>
    <AssetCrossReference AssetID="F7961393-02" Type="Colour Photograph"/>
 </AssetCrossReferences><Specification Ordered="true">
```

I want the end result to look like this:

```
AssetID:F7961393-01, Type:Primary Image
AssetID:M0504-01, Type:Vendor Logo
AssetID:F7961393-02, Type:Colour Photograph
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Post your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  a Struct

```
create external table test 
(
   asset STRUCT<AssetID:STRING,Type:STRING>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
with serdeproperties 
(
  "column.xpath.asset"="/AssetCrossReferences/AssetCrossReference"
)
stored as inputformat "com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat"
outputformat "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat"
location "file:///yourfilepath" 
tblproperties 
(
  "xmlinput.start"="<AssetCrossReferences",
  "xmlinput.end"="</AssetCrossReferences>"
);
```

Then

```
select * from test;
```